Validate string as javascript code in VSCode
In my app developed in react typescript environment using VSCode I have an iframe into which I'm inserting css styles and scripts:
scripts.ts
export const scriptString = 'window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // valid js code here to be validated by IDE
})';

component.tsx
import { scriptString } from './scripts';
.
.
.

const iframeHead = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const scriptElement = iframeDocument.createElement('script');

scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
scriptElement.innerText = scriptString;

iframeHead.appendChild(scriptElement);

Since I didn't found any other way to import the content of the .js file than using fetch API and exposing the script file as a public asset I'm looking for possibility to validate the string content of a constant as javascript code.
Is there any possibility to achieve this in VSCode?
